# How can I work with BitmapFactory.options?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

please look at following code:

```
public Pixmap newPixmap(String fileName, PixmapFormat format) {
        Config config = null;
        if (format == PixmapFormat.RGB565)
            config = Config.RGB_565;
        else if (format == PixmapFormat.ARGB4444)
            config = Config.ARGB_4444;
        else
            config = Config.ARGB_8888;

        Options options = new Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = config;

        InputStream in = null;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            in = assets.open(fileName);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            if (bitmap == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load bitmap from asset '"
                        + fileName + "'");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load bitmap from asset '"
                    + fileName + "'");
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }

        if (bitmap.getConfig() == Config.RGB_565)
            format = PixmapFormat.RGB565;
        else if (bitmap.getConfig() == Config.ARGB_4444)
            format = PixmapFormat.ARGB4444;
        else
            format = PixmapFormat.ARGB8888;

        return new AndroidPixmap(bitmap, format);
    }
```

I don't understand this part:

```
Options options = new Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = config;
```

It looks like, that the programmer tries to configure the Format of the loading bitmap. I know that the Options-Class is a nested class of BitmapFactory.

But anywhere in code the object options is used. Why?

And why is there an if request to get the format, when I used the optionss object to configure the format before I load the bitmap?

I am confused. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your code is coming from but if you want (I suspect you do) want to use the `Options` object, then you should change your `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);` to use it like so: `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);`

Comment: This code is taken from a book and therefore I am confused about these needless lines. And I am asking myself why the author did not use the method Bitmap decodeFile(String pathName, Options opts)? If he had used this method, the code would have been 20 lines shorter, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The decoder will try to decode into this internal configuration for this:
options.inPreferredConfig = config;
Basically config is:
A bitmap configuration describes how pixels are stored. This affects the quality (color depth) as well as the ability to display transparent/translucent colors. 
Read this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html